# SVG image element with crisp edges

Tags: svg

I have an SVG which includes a PNG image using `<image>`. This included image is a pixel art and I would like it to show pixelated.

But instead it is showing blurry.

**Can I change the display so it is pixelated?**

Minimal test case:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image
    width="100"
    height="100"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAABCAIAAAB7QOjdAAAAD0lEQVR4AWP48OotAwMDAA3tAsiMG69RAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  />
</svg>
```

Inside is a PNG with dimensions two pixels wide and one pixel tall.

Here is how it displayed on macOS 12.1 (21C52) / Safari 15.2 (17612.3.6.1.6).

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimal SVG with a test image. You can add a filter to retain pixelation, but the implementation depends on the image

Comment: @MichaelMullany got it minified down, updated question

Answer (score 3):

Styling the `<image>` element with `image-rendering: pixelated` achieves the desired result:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image style="image-rendering: pixelated;" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAABCAIAAAB7QOjdAAAAD0lEQVR4AWP48OotAwMDAA3tAsiMG69RAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
</svg>
```

> The **`image-rendering`** CSS property sets an image scaling algorithm. The property applies to an element itself, to any images set in its other properties, and to its descendants.
>
> — [MDN Web Docs: Image Rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

Note, this doesn't appear to render correctly in Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Well the right way would be to use `image-rendering: pixelated` - but that's not supported on Safari yet.

Until then - this filter will work on black and white pixel art - transforming all RG & B values between 0 and 127 -> 0 and all values from 128 to 255 -> 255. (If you have scaled up anti-aliasing that you want to squash, you should add another `<feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>` to that list of feFunc's in the filter).

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <defs>
    <filter id="crispen">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
        <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
        <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image
    filter="url(#crispen)"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAABCAIAAAB7QOjdAAAAD0lEQVR4AWP48OotAwMDAA3tAsiMG69RAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  />
</svg>
```

You can also generalize this to duo-tone pixel art by specifying different arrays for tableValues. If your dark tones is rgb(40,60,70) and your light tone is rgb (250,200,180) then your feComponentTransfer would be:

```
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0.156 .98"/>
    <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0.235 .784"/>
    <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0.274 .706"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
```

(e.g. - when you unitize the lower red value of 40 - you get 40/255 = .156)

Note that this only works when all the lower and upper RGB values are lower and higher than 127.5. For example, if your light tone is rgb(200,50,50) and your dark tone is (50,60,60) - then this will result in the wrong answer. In this case you have to create a longer (and more complex) tableValues array so that the source colors are converted to the right destination color.

Comment: This doesn't work for monochrome images that have values other than black and white.

Comment: Ah good point - will add to the answer